# Update Facebook Status via SMS application

Tags: php, facebook

We have a request from a client to update facebook status/comments through a text message.

Here is the scenario.

The SMS carries the fb Username,Password and the status/comments and this will goes to a SMS Gateway. Then the USername,Password and the status/comments come to our application and our application should facilitate to update the status and comments on the fb account.

Is there a method to authenticate the user through a SMS (Auth Dialog box) or is there any other method to update status/comments on fb through a sms. This is a PHP application.

Comment: I don't think the API allows that (shouldn't). Create an application on Facebook and authorize your users through OAuth. Then use the access tokens generated, and then you should be able to use the Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why don't you ask your user to create an account on your site and authorize your Facebook registered App to access his timeline? He would also register his phone number on your site and get a short numeric unique ID.
2. Then he can just send an SMS and when you detect a phone number or the numeric ID in a SMS, you post with the Facebook API which you are authorized for.

Sending Username and Password via SMS is not a great idea. A numeric ID of the phone number itself is much safer.

**PS**: *I'm not using FBAPI but this is how it's supposed to work, from what I heard.*

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to authenticate using username and password.

you should ask your users to create new application on their profile or authenticate first via your website in order to grant you an access.

after obtaining application_key and application_secret you can manipulate with user's account using these pairs.

please refer to facebook's developer zone to get more details on how fbapi works.